# Two animations on the same component

Tags: angular, animation

I'm creating an angular component and inside it I'm trying to use 2 animations with the angular library / angular animations. But I am not able to use one animation inside the other, the first animation is always the one executed, the second one has no animation.

I wonder if this is possible or not?

Here's the image of how I'm using the animations
[image]

Comment: Have a look here to solve you issue - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to execute animations in a sequence, first parent div then the button?

If so, please look into animateChild, you will find ur answer.